# Solving $_{a}C_{r}+_{a}C_{r-1} \cdot _{b}C_{1}+\dotsb+_{b}C_{r}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

This is a problem I'm having trouble understanding. 
I have to evaluate the value of 
$$
_{a}C_{r}+_{a}C_{r-1}\cdot _{b}C_{1}+ _{a}C_{r-2} \cdot _{b}C_{2}+\dotsb+_{b}C_{r}
$$

The answer given is $_{(a+b)}C_{r}$

I can't think of any ways to get to this solution. I tried expanding $_{(a+b)}C_{r}$ but ended up with a gigantic mess. Any clues to get to this solution would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Choosing $r$ things from $a+b$ things, you can choose all $r$ out of the first $a$, or only $r-1$ out of the first $a$ and $1$ out of the last $b$, or $r-2$ out of the first $a$ and $2$ out of the last $b$....

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Compare coefficients in the binomial expansions of both sides of the identity
$$ (1+x)^a(1+x)^b = (1+x)^{a+b}. $$
This is called [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

Comment: Understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Note that $(1+x)^{a+b}=(1+x)^a(1+x)^b$.

Compare the coefficient of $x^{r}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{r}{a \choose r - k}{b \choose k} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{b \choose k}\bracks{z^{r - k}}\pars{1 + z}^{a} =
\bracks{z^{r}}\pars{1 + z}^{a}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{b \choose k}z^{k}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{r}}\pars{1 + z}^{a}\pars{1 + z}^{b} =
\bracks{z^{r}}\pars{1 + z}^{a + b} = \bbx{a + b \choose r}
\end{align}